# Pandas function to linearise a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Often I want to linearise a dataframe.
For example,

```
  a b 
1 l m
2 n o
```

to

```
columns index value 
      a     1     l
      b     1     m
      a     2     n    
      b     2     o
```

I use this custom code to linearise a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
def unstack2df(df,coln='columns',idxn='index',col='value'):
    if df.columns.name is None:
        df.columns.name=coln
    if df.index.name is None:
        df.index.name=idxn
    df=df.unstack()
    df.name=col
    return pd.DataFrame(df).reset_index()
```

I wonder if there is any in built module in pandas that can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) after elevating your index to a series. You may then sort and rename columns / rows if necessary.

```
res = pd.melt(df.assign(index=df.index), id_vars=['index'])

print(res)

   index variable value
0      1        a     l
1      2        a     n
2      1        b     m
3      2        b     o
```

A more verbose, but equivalent, version:

```
df = df.reset_index()    
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'])
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
df.unstack().rename_axis(['columns', 'index']).reset_index(name = 'value')
```

Output:

```
  columns  index value
0       a      1     l
1       a      2     n
2       b      1     m
3       b      2     o
```